# Data scraping with scrapy

Tags: java, database, scrapy, web-crawler

i want to make a new betting tool, but i need a database of odds and results and can't find anything in the web. I found this site that has great archive: [OddsPortal](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/italy/serie-a-2003-2004/results/)

All i want to do is scrape the results and the odds from page like the one above. I found that a tool called Scrapy can do it, is it true? Can someone help me with some hints?

Comment: Possible copyright issues aside, you may have trouble getting useful answers here.  This site focuses on specific programming questions: "I tried `this`, and got `that` as a result".   It doesn't work tend to well with open-ended questions like yours.

Comment: ty for the answer, and where i can ask for this?

Comment: In this case, it appears that Austin gave you a `very` good answer. Please remember to `Accept` it. In the general case, I'm not sure - I'd have probably just downloaded Scrapy and started trying, myself. If I ran into trouble, I'd have then come here or the Scrapy forum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about Scrapy, but JSoup should help you get you started.

http://jsoup.org/

Download the .jar file. Right click your project folder > Properties > Java build path > libraries > add external jars > find the jar and click it.

It's a nice little HTML parser

Here's an example.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class HtmlParser {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794913/data-scraping-with-scrapy";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    String question = document.select(".question .postcell").text();

    System.out.println(question);
}
```

This will print your question :P

Right click this webpage and hit inspect element.

Then find the element you want and put the name of it's class (or ID) in the document.select() part in this case ".question .postcell". (.parentClass .childClass)

If you need extra help there is a guide on the jsoup website

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

I was board so I threw together a little something that fetches all the Italy soccer scores in the 2003-2004 year,  enjoy :D - link - http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/italy/serie-a-2003-2004/results/

```
public class HtmlParser {

    String url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/italy/serie-a-2003-2004/results/";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    Elements stats = document.select("#tournamentTable tbody tr");

    for(int i = 0; i < stats.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(stats.get(i).text());
    }
}

Output:

Soccer» Italy»Serie A 2003/2004

1 X 2 B's


AC Milan - Brescia 4:2 - - - 6

Chievo - Bologna 2:1 - - - 5

Empoli - Inter 2:3 - - - 5

Parma - Udinese 4:3 - - - 5

Lazio - Modena 2:1 - - - 4

Lecce - Reggina 2:1 - - - 5

Perugia - Ancona 1:0 - - - 1

Sampdoria - AS Roma 0:0 - - - 4

Siena - Juventus 1:3 - - - 5

1 X 2 B's



Ancona - Empoli 2:1 - - - 1

AS Roma - Perugia 1:3 - - - 3

Bologna - Lecce 1:1 - - - 7

Brescia - Lazio 2:1 - - - 1

Inter - Parma 1:0 - - - 7

Juventus - Sampdoria 2:0 - - - 7

Modena - Siena 1:3 - - - 7

Reggina - AC Milan 2:1 - - - 1

Udinese - Chievo 1:1 - - - 3

1 X 2 B's



AC Milan - AS Roma 1:0 - - - 6

Parma - Ancona 3:1 - - - 3

Lazio - Reggina 1:1 - - - 6

Lecce - Inter 2:1 - - - 6

Perugia - Juventus 1:0 - - - 4

Sampdoria - Udinese 1:3 - - - 5

Siena - Brescia 0:1 - - - 3

1 X 2 B's



Ancona - Chievo 0:2 - - - 3

AS Roma - Empoli 3:0 - - - 6

Inter - Lazio 0:0 - - - 6

Juventus - Lecce 3:4 - - - 6

Modena - Sampdoria 1:0 - - - 5

Reggina - Parma 1:1 - - - 5

Udinese - AC Milan 0:0 - - - 6

1 X 2 B's



Lazio - AS Roma 1:1 - - - 7

1 X 2 B's



Modena - AS Roma 0:1 - - - 6

Chievo - Reggina 0:0 - - - 4

Empoli - Brescia 1:1 - - - 5

Parma - Juventus 2:2 - - - 6

Inter - Bologna 4:2 - - - 6

Lazio - Ancona 4:2 - - - 5

Sampdoria - Perugia 3:2 - - - 6

1 X 2 B's



Lecce - Udinese 2:1 - - - 6

Siena - AC Milan 1:2 - - - 5

1 X 2 B's



Perugia - Inter 2:3 - - - 7

1 X 2 B's



Juventus - Lazio 1:0 - - - 7

AC Milan - Empoli 1:0 - - - 7

Ancona - Bologna 3:2 - - - 7

AS Roma - Chievo 3:1 - - - 7

Brescia - Modena 0:0 - - - 7

Reggina - Udinese 0:1 - - - 7



Siena - Sampdoria 0:0 - - - 7
```

so cool!

Comment: thank you very much! i own you a beer! ;)

Comment: @Austin Excellent answer.  Too bad the community decided to close the question.