# What is right way to combine (AND) several conditions for nested CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to specify that what I want (`<b>19</b>`, etc) is simultaneously

1. within `class="elem"` and `class="main"` (descending CSS combinator- space)
2. direct children (CSS > immediate child combinator) of class="numbers" > class="numbers_wrapper" > class="container cleared"

What is the correct way how can I combine all those 5 conditions?

I need to extract this info

```
                <b>19</b>
                <b>12</b>
                <b>14</b>
                <b>23</b>
                <b>10</b>
```

from this pattern in the middle of a web page :

```
<div class="elem">
<div class="main">
    <div class="draw_date" title="08.04.2018 21:00">08.04.2018 21:00</div>
    <div class="draw">
        <a href="/5x36plus/archive/8277">8277</a>
    </div>


    <div class="numbers">
        <div class="numbers_wrapper">
            <div class="container cleared">
                <b>19</b>
                <b>12</b>
                <b>14</b>
                <b>23</b>
                <b>10</b>
                <b class="extra">02</b>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="controls">
            <a class="no_visited iconic nonunderline" title="Проверить билет"
                href="/5x36plus/check_bulletin">⚲</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="prize  ">
        <div class="jackpot_wrapper">
            <span></span>
            <span>3000000
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="jackpot_wrapper">
            <span></span>
            <span>3437960
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is my guess how to do it right?

```
div.elem > div.main div.numbers > div.numbers_wrapper > div.container.cleared b
```

P.S. I am [using Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) web scraping lib for java (like here [in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794913/data-scraping-with-scrapy)), it grabs info from web page if I correctly specify target CSS selectors combination.

Comment: why you can't just use div.container.cleared b{}

Comment: I am afraid some element with class = "contaner cleared"  may be also in some other place (surrounded by other tags) which is not wanted. I want to exclude its happening in any other context

Comment: if you want to select only particular  elements , you may give ID to certain block

Comment: thank you for this advise, but I am parsing a very complex third-party web site I have no control of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It's absolutely right. But as far as you've defined your class name differently you can also simply describe your css as .cleared b{}.

```css
div.elem > div.main div.numbers > div.numbers_wrapper > div.container.cleared b{color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
<div class="main">
    <div class="draw_date" title="08.04.2018 21:00">08.04.2018 21:00</div>
    <div class="draw">
        <a href="/5x36plus/archive/8277">8277</a>
    </div>


    <div class="numbers">
        <div class="numbers_wrapper">
            <div class="container cleared">
                <b>19</b>
                <b>12</b>
                <b>14</b>
                <b>23</b>
                <b>10</b>
                <b class="extra">02</b>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="controls">
            <a class="no_visited iconic nonunderline" title="Проверить билет"
                href="/5x36plus/check_bulletin">⚲</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="prize  ">
        <div class="jackpot_wrapper">
            <span></span>
            <span>3000000
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="jackpot_wrapper">
            <span></span>
            <span>3437960
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you much for approving!  The code I wrote above worked 100% as expected, just as you confirmed!

Comment: Pleasure is mine..Thank you for appreciation. :)